# Derivative of the Normal CDF w.r.t. its mean.

Tags: integration, derivatives, normal-distribution, means, cumulative-distribution-functions

I want to know how to take the derivative of a Normal CDF w.r.t its mean using a more general method than using the normalization function.

A Normal CDF is definied by $\Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$. Using chain rule is straight forward to calculated its derivative w.r.t. its mean:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} F(x)= \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})  = - \frac{1}{\sigma} \phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})
\end{equation}
I would like to get the same result using the proper CDF Function.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} F(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2} dx
\end{equation}
**MY TRIAL** (verified by online calculators):

The bounds of the integral are not a function of $\mu$ so (by Leibiniz Rule) the derivative can go inside:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2} dx=\int_{-\infty}^x  \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2} dx = \int_{-\infty}^x  \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2} · (- \frac{-2x+2\mu}{2\sigma^2} )dx
\end{equation}
Simplifying terms and rearrengin conviniently the last term becomes
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x  e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2} ·  \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \frac{1}{\sigma}  dx
\end{equation}
Using Change of Variable:
\begin{equation}
z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \Rightarrow \frac{dz}{dx}= \frac{1}{\sigma} \Rightarrow dx= \sigma dz
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x  e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2} ·  z \frac{1}{\sigma} \sigma dz = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}\left[-e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2} \right]^x_{-\infty} =\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}\left[-e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2} \right]^x_{-\infty} = -\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2} = -\phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})
\end{equation}
If we compare it with the inital statement, there is *a $1/\sigma$ missing*. Introducing the derivative in an online calculator and the result into a calculuator of integrals gives exactly the same result. So I'm going crazy with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your last equality is wrong. The factor $\frac1{\sigma}$ on LHS is (fortunately) not wiped away (as you seem to think) and should also appear on RHS.

Comment: the $\frac{1}{\sigma}$ is also part of the Normal Pdf and so it is inside $\phi(\cdot)$

Comment: @Joan You should change the $x$ variable inside the integrals to something else... It should not coincide with the variable used as an integration limit.

Comment: Meanwhile you flip it back to the previous variable before substitute the limits it would not matter...  I could put $x=\mu + z\sigma$ in the upper limit, but when I change it bakc I would get the same

Comment: I am not talking about the $\frac1{\sigma}$ *inside*.

Comment: My fault, I though it was implicitely inside the $\phi$ as part of the pdf function, but it is the SN Pdf which makes my point wrong. Your answer is correct, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The last equality in your answer is false.
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12x^2}=\phi(x)$$ so that: $$-\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}=-\frac1{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$

Comment: OKEY I see your point now. THANKS A LOT and SORRY for DOUBTING IT BEFORE!!! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Small things can drive me crazy as well. Especially in maths.